# Splitting strings after scraping table from data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am scraping data from a webpage, and want to see if there is an easy way to separate the strings. The total length is 100 different alt coins containing name, price, circulating supply and volume supply. The name contains the name and sumbol.

Ex: BitcoinBTC
Goal: Separate the name from symbol, so i only get the name

Prices has the dollar sign
Ex: $1.00
Goal: separate the dollar sign, so I only get the value

Circulating and volume supply have vale and symbol

Ex: 1,000,000 BTC
Goal: separate so I only get the value

I can do this, but the problem is that the scraping is done in a loop and stored in a dictionary. I then create a dataframe outside of the loop.

```
coin_name = coin_name.split('\n')[0]
prices = prices.split('$')[1]
market_caps = market_caps.split('$')[1]
cir_sup = cir_sup.split()[0]
volume_sup = volume_sup.split()[0]
```

This is inside the loop:

```
results = [{"Alt coin name": coin.text, "Price": price.text,
                "Market cap": cap.text, "Circulating supply":cir.text,
                "Volume": vol.text} for coin, price, cap, cir, vol in zip(coin_name, prices, market_caps, cir_sup, volume_sup)]
```

Comment: Isn't it a lot of code just to separate a string ? Please provide MWE, shorten your code and remove unnecessary parts.

Comment: question is updated now, sorry for the inconvience

Comment: Can you share the website you are gathering data from?

Comment: It is from coinmarketcap.com. I have created a loop where I extracted coin name, price, market cap, circulating supply and volume supply. I stored the values in a dictionary and created a dataframe. I exported the data to excel. I get the right output in terms of what I am scraping, but I want to separate unwanted information.

Comment: You can get data from the API that the pages calls. Let me write a sample code

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Thank you for the information, but i am aware of this. I wanted to write some code where I extract it without the api. But now, the only thing missing is just to separate strings.

Comment: If you want to use BeautifulSoup, you can do that too. Would you like a sample code for that?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I have a sample code, but I will be very happy if you could share yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226415/discussion-between-prayson-w-daniel-and-dfhaa-dk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is populate by GET Restful API call.

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
URI = "https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"

params = dict(
        start=101,
        limit=100,
        sort='market_cap',
        sort_dir='desc',
        convert='USD',
        cryptocurrency_type='all',
        aux='circulating_supply,max_supply,total_supply'
)

headers = {'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) '
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
           'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'),
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

session.headers.update(headers)

# probably you can put this in a while-loop and call it every N-time
# as the data updates
r = session.get(URI, params=params)

data = r.json()
print(data)
```

Using BeautifulSoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/1/'

r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')

#columns = ' '.join([item.get_text(',') for item in table.find('thead').find_all('tr')]).split(',')

rows = [i.split(',') for i in [item.get_text(',') for item in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')]]

print(rows)
```

Comment: Thank so much for taking time to help me :)